# Playing a music file in the music library

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

how do I play a song from the music library? I tried this:

```
private void click_AlarmSet(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    play();
}  

async private void play()
{
    var openPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

    openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation =Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;
    openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("toxic.mp3");

    var file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

    sound.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
    sound.Play();
}
```

here `sound` is my media element and "toxic.mp3" is the mp3 file I want to play, but the mp3 is not playing.

Comment: As I understand you want to play file in the client , but you code refferenced to the server side . Is that correct ?

Comment: I retagged this as a windows store app - I hope this is correct. @GregoryNozik, I'm assuming this isn't really asp.net.

Comment: oh...how do I play the file in the client?. i'm new into app development...yes this is windows store app

Answer (score 1):

```
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("toxic.mp3")
```

I think that the FileTypeFilter is looking for ".mp3" or ".wav" not a specific file name.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.filetypefilter.Aspx

Suggestion:

```
var name = "toxic.mp3";
var file = await openPicker.GetFileAsync(name);
var stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
sound.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
```

-Or-
If you wanted all the '.mp3'

```
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3")
```